# Android app crashes in blackberry phones while wrapping the cipher

Tags: android, encoding, blackberry

In my android application password is saved to db after encode. While doing so it undergoes cipher.wrap to obtain the secret key.

This works fine in android phones but in blackberry devices running on 7.1.1 and 8.0.0 it crashes with the below log, initiated from cipher.wrap.

```
com.blackberry.security.crypto.provider.b.b: 
  at com.blackberry.security.crypto.provider.b.a.k (Error.java:27)
  at com.blackberry.security.crypto.provider.cipher.AESCipherSpi.engineWrap 
(AESCipherSpi.java:188)
  at javax.crypto.Cipher.wrap (Cipher.java:2074)
```

Cipher is created like this:

```
Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
```

Wrapping happens passing the secret key:

```
cipher.wrap(<secretKey>)
```

There is no clue on why this happens on specific blackberry devices alone. Seeking help to resolve the crash, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably the wrapper or cipher is not available on those devices.

Comment: Do you mean that the device libraries doesn't have them or code is missing some part? The device was updated to latest OS also.

Comment: That the device library does not have this wrapper. It is not defined in the Android standard I believe which wrappers should be supported.

Comment: Well, do you see any other way to escape from crash?

Comment: You could try catch it and use another algorithm in the catch, but I am not sure if that is what you want.